# Blocking Connections By IP

Tags: c#, .net

I need to able to block any and all connections to my pc from a specific IP address , i know this is possible with a firewall but i need to do this in c#. Any idea how (need code).

Update :
Its a generic C# app not asp.net , target platform is WinXp till Win7

Comment: Are you asking how to write a generic firewall app in C#?  Or are you asking this in the context of an ASP.Net app running under IIS?  Or what?

Comment: Are you looking to update the firewall from code or just to ignore requests to your code from a specific IP address? If it's the latter then it's not a very good way of doing things your system is going to be actively receiving data from the IP and ignoring it rather than having the firewall blocking it in the first instance. Also, what is the target platform? Lastly, have you any code that you've tried and hasn't delivered what you were looking for? If so, then please post it and tell us how it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need more information... if you're talking socket communication, you can simply close the connection to a client as soon as it connects if the IP address is blocked, or process the Connection Request and evaluate there.

**Edit:** Simplest way for you would probably just be to interact with Windows Firewall API... here's how:

http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/controlling-win.html

Comment: That sounds good if not exactly what i need , just not sure how to go about doing it , article's/code would help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but I'll try to answer the best I can, within my understanding.

1. Do you want to control machines from connecting to any port on your machine? if so, you need to control the built-in windows firewall or find yourself a filter driver you can control. In order to write your own filter driver, you must leave the land of managed code, so I am guessing that's not an option.

To learn how to control the firewall, here's a link:

http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/controlling-win.html

more on google.

2. Do you want to control remote machines from connection to a port on your machines that your application owns? You cannot do that either (see #1 above). However you can take action after the connection, and close the connection if you don't like the remote IP (check the remote endpoint's IP).

two caveats with this approach:

It doesn't save you from a DoS attack.
You will need to be careful if you need ipv6 support (you can't just check the IPV4 address in that case)

HTH

Comment: I dont mind going into unmanged code , just prefer using managed code

Answer (score 0):

A "firewall" in c#?

First you would have to access the network interface on a low level, eg.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms817945.aspx

Then you have to parse all incoming packets and maybe discard them.

It's not an easy task and I don't recommend you to write a driver and a firewall in C#, because the .NET Framework will be loaded every time you start your machine. 
Also traffic parsing can be tricky... I implemented a router/traffic analyzer in C# some time ago and it took me about one year to gain the experience with network programming to gain the knowledge to do this.